# useUserContext Provider Not Sending Data to Profile Page

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

## Issue Description

I am facing a problem where the data stored in the `useUserContext` doesn't seem to be passed properly from the Login page to the Profile page in my React application. I have thoroughly checked my code, and even though the data is successfully logged in the `useUserContext`, it appears as `null` in the Profile page.

## Code Samples

useUserContext.js

```
import { createContext, useState, useContext } from 'react';

const UserContext = createContext();

export function useUserContext() {
  return useContext(UserContext);
}

export function UserContextProvider({ children }) {
  const [user, setUser] = useState(null);

  return (
    <UserContext.Provider value={{ user, setUser }}>
      {children}
    </UserContext.Provider>
  );
}
```

App.js

```
import React from 'react';
import { Route, Routes } from 'react-router-dom';
import "./styles/signup.css";
import "./styles/login.css";
import "./styles/profile.css";
import Navbar from './components/Navbar';
import Signup from './components/Signup';
import Login from "./components/Login";
import Homepage from './components/Homepage';
import Notifications from './components/Notifications';
import Profile from './components/Profile';
import Interpage from './components/Interpage';
import Yourvideos from './components/Yourvideos';
import Tagline from './components/Tagline';
import Trending from './components/Trending';
import { UserContextProvider } from "./components/Usercontext";
import CreateVideo from './components/Createvideo';

function App() {
  const isCreateVideo = window.location.pathname.startsWith('/createvideo');

  return (
    <div>
      <UserContextProvider>
        {!isCreateVideo && <Navbar />}
        {!isCreateVideo && <Interpage />}
        <Routes>
          <Route exact path="/" element={<Signup />} />
          <Route exact path="/login" element={<Login />} />
          <Route exact path="/home" element={<Homepage />} />
          <Route exact path="/notifications" element={<Notifications />} />
          <Route exact path="/profile" element={<Profile />} />
          <Route exact path="/yourvideos" element={<Yourvideos />} />
          <Route exact path="/tagline" element={<Tagline />} />
          <Route exact path="/trending" element={<Trending />} />
          <Route exact path="/createvideo" element={<CreateVideo />} />
        </Routes>
      </UserContextProvider>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Profile.jsx

```
import React from 'react';
import userImage from '../images/Profile.jpg';
import { useUserContext } from './Usercontext';

const Profile = () => {
  const { user } = useUserContext();

  return (
    <div className="page-container">
      <div className="profile-page-container">
        <div className="profile-row">
          <div className="profile-box user-image-box">
            <img src={userImage} alt="User" className="user-image round-user-image" />
          </div>
          <div className="profile-box name-box">
            <i className="fa-solid fa-user"></i>
            <span className="element-label">Name:</span>
            <span className="element-value">{user && user[0]}</span>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div className="profile-row">
          <div className="profile-box email-box">
            <i className="fa-solid fa-envelope"></i>
            <span className="element-label">Email:</span>
            <span className="element-value">{user && user[1]}</span>
          </div>
          <div className="profile-box phone-box">
            <i className="fa-solid fa-phone"></i>
            <span className="element-label">Phone:</span>
            <span className="element-value">{user && user[2]}</span>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div className="profile-row">
          <div className="profile-box dob-box">
            <i className="fa-solid fa-calendar"></i>
            <span className="element-label">Date of Birth:</span>
            <span className="element-value">{user && user[3]}</span>
          </div>
          <div className="profile-box dob-box">
            <i className="fa-solid fa-location-pin"></i>
            <span className="element-label">Location:</span>
            <span className="element-value">{user && user[4]}</span>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div className="user-bio">
          <h2>Bio</h2>
          <p>
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.
          </p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Profile;
```

Login.jsx

```
import React from 'react';
import { useState } from 'react';
import { useUserContext } from './Usercontext';
import { useNavigate } from 'react-router-dom';
import { getDocs, collection, query, where } from 'firebase/firestore';
import { db } from './firebaseconfig';

const Login = () => {
  const Navigate = useNavigate();
  const [data, setData] = useState({
    email: '',
    password: ''
  });
  const { setUser } = useUserContext();

  const handleInput = (event) => {
    let newInput = { [event.target.name]: event.target.value };
    setData({ ...data, ...newInput });
  };

  const handleLogin = async (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();

    const { email, password } = data;

    const usersRef = collection(db, 'users');
    const q = query(usersRef, where('email', '==', email));
    const querySnapshot = await getDocs(q);

    if (querySnapshot.empty) {
      alert('Login failed: User not found');
      return;
    }

    const userDoc = querySnapshot.docs[0];
    const userData = userDoc.data();
    const userArray = [userData.name, userData.email, userData.phoneNumber, userData.dob, userData.country];

    if (userData.password === password && userData.email === email) {
      setTimeout(() => {
        setUser(userArray);
        Navigate('/home');
      }, 1000);
    } else {
      alert('Login failed: Incorrect password');
    }
  };

  return (
    <div className='login_page'>
      <div className='login_box'>
        <form className='login_input_box' action='/login'>
          <h2 className='login_top_topic'>Login</h2>

          <div className='login-wrapper-input'>
            <i id='i_tags' className='fa-solid fa-envelope'></i>
            <input
              type='email'
              name='email'
              onChange={handleInput}
              placeholder='Email'
              autoComplete='off'
              value={data.email}
            />
          </div>

          <div className='login-wrapper-input'>
            <i id='i_tags' className='fa-solid fa-lock'></i>
            <input
              type='password'
              name='password'
              onChange={handleInput}
              placeholder='Password'
              autoComplete='off'
              value={data.password}
            />
          </div>

          <button className='login_button' onClick={handleLogin}>
            Login
          </button>
        </form>
        <p className='Not_have_Account'>
          Not Have Account <a className='Not_have_Account_p' href='/'>
            Create a Account
          </a>
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Login;
```

Comment: I don't see any overt issues with the code after a quick glance. How are you navigating from the login page on `"/login"` to the profile page on `"/profile"`? Are you just manually editing the path in the browser's address bar? Doing this reloads the page and remounts the entire app, which means the `user` state is reset to the initial `null` value.

Comment: No i am not doing it manually i have navlinks if you see in my app.js i have navbar and interpage navbar is my navbar and in my interpage i have profile section when i click on it will go to /profile

Comment: i am using react know react does not reloads the page know this is my interpage in when i click on it .it will go to profile page
const Interpage = () => {
  return (
    
        <div className="cards_div_down_xyzab">
          <a href="/profile"><img src={profile_img} alt="" /></a>
          <p>DILIP KUMAR</p>
          
        </div>
      </div>
      <p className="Interpage_main_verticaline_rsdab"></p>
    </div>
  );
}

export default Interpage;

Answer (score 0):

It would appear that you are using raw anchor tags to effect navigations around your app. These make a request to the server and reload the page with the new URL path, thus the app remounts and the `user` state is initialized to the `null` value.

Instead of raw anchor tags you should import and render the `Link` or `NavLink` component from `react-router-dom`.

Example:

```
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';

const Interpage = () => {
  return (
    <div className="cards_div_down_xyzab">
      <div>
        <Link to="/profile">
          <img src={profile_img} alt="" />
        </Link>
        <p>DILIP KUMAR</p>
      </div>
      <p className="Interpage_main_verticaline_rsdab" /> 
    </div>
  );
};

export default Interpage;
```

You can also optimize your `App` component by using a layout out to exclude the navigation components on the `"/createvideo"` route.

```
import { Route, Routes, Outlet } from 'react-router-dom';

const NavLayout = () => (
  <>
    <Navbar />
    <Interpage />
    <Outlet />
  </>
);

function App() {
  return (
    <div>
      <UserContextProvider>
        <Routes>
          {/* Render with navbars */}
          <Route element={<NavLayout />}>
            <Route path="/" element={<Signup />} />
            <Route path="/login" element={<Login />} />
            <Route path="/home" element={<Homepage />} />
            <Route path="/notifications" element={<Notifications />} />
            <Route path="/profile" element={<Profile />} />
            <Route path="/yourvideos" element={<Yourvideos />} />
            <Route path="/tagline" element={<Tagline />} />
            <Route path="/trending" element={<Trending />} />
          </Route>

          {/* Render without navbars */}
          <Route path="/createvideo" element={<CreateVideo />} />
        </Routes>
      </UserContextProvider>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: Very Very thank you the data came and thanks for extra changes in my app component of Navlayout